# Does this cast mean a broken polymorphism design?

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism

I have an interface which defines a "module":

```
public interface AIMModule {
    // Details not relevant
}
```

and another which defines a container for those modules:

```
public interface AIMModuleContainer {
    public void addModule( AIMModule module );  
}
```

These "modules" are actually GUI constructs, so the implementation of my container extends the HLayout widget of the GUI toolkit I'm using. It contains a SectionStack called moduleStack. SectionStack.addSection( SectionStackSection ) adds a section stack into the GUI, so my "modules" container abstraction looks like this:

```
public class UserContainer extends HLayout implements AIMModuleContainer {

@Override
public void addModule( AIMModule module )
{
    moduleStack.addSection( (SectionStackSection)module );
}

}
```

The module implementation therefore extends a widget called SectionStackSection:

```
public class AccountInformationModule extends SectionStackSection implements AIMModule {
    // Details not relevant
}
```

The problem is that cast in addModule() where it calls addSection(). The AIMModuleContainer contains AIMModules, and so the addModule() needs to the take a AIMModule. But at the implementation level, the moduleStack widget inserts a SectionStackSection, so the interface's "module" needs to be cast according to the implementation.

This works, but it feels wrong. If someone implements my AIMModule interface by extending something other than SectionStackSection and passes that AIMModule into addModule(), that cast will break. That doesn't seem right.

Is this broken? If it is, what's the approach that fixes it?

Comment: UserContainer is not an AIMModuleContainer because it can't contain AIMModules. so you "fix" it by not implementing AIMModuleContainer.

Comment: you could also make use of Visitor in order to benefit of double dispatching, typically what you need here .

Answer (score 2):

This is broken, as you never check that the argument passed is the type you expect it to be, and even then, it should just take in the type you expect it to be. But this is impossible as your module container can contain any type of module.

Does each module container only handle one type? If so, make use Generics. If not, this is just overall a bad implementation, as you assume it will always be something that it is not.

Comment: Yes, the module container only handles one type. The current implementation is SmartGWT, so I'm using that toolkit's SectionStackSection. I'm going to have to implement at least once more, so need to ensure I don't leak anything from SmartGWT into this modules interface. Can you expand a little on how generics can be used to achieve this?

Comment: Make the ModuleContainer class be `AIMModuleContainer<M extends AIMModule>` then make the set method take in `M module`, and the get method return `M`, so a AIMModuleContainer<AccountInformationModule> will return a AccountInformationModule from it's get, and you can then make your addModule method in user container paramtized with AccountInformationModule too (`implements AIMModuleContainer<AccountInformationModule>`)

Comment: Thanks for your help. On reflection the right thing to do here was rip out what I had, think about it, then do it again properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have provided, what you seem to need is an interface `SectionStackContainer` that should be implemented by `UserContainer`

```
public interface SectionStackContainer {
    public void addSectionStack( SectionStack sectionStack );  
}

public class UserContainer extends HLayout implements SectionStackContainer {

    @Override
    public void addSectionStack( SectionStack sectionStack )
    {
        moduleStack.addSection( sectionStack );
    }

}
```